# Android Studio is taking up memory in Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm, java

[image]
I use Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5. When building app the memory usage increased crazily. I have 16 GB RAM. But apparently this is not enough sometimes. It goes up to 4GB from time to time. I end up needing to close other applications to free up memory. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Android studio always eats the RAM alive. Just see the minimum requirements of RAM. 8 GB.

Comment: Try using 32bit android-studio

Comment: @Arsf u got  any solutions ?

Comment: @JithishPN Unfortunately no. I instead upgraded my desktop's memory from 16GB to 32GB.